# Strictly monotone norms

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove the next statement.

Let $‖⋅‖_{z}$ an strictly monotone norm and  $W=(ℝ^{2},‖⋅‖_{z})$. Then for every ε > 0, there exists δ(ε) > 0 such that if (a,b), (a,c) belong to the unit ball $B_{W}$ and $‖(a,b)‖-‖(a,c)‖<δ(ε)$ then $|b|-|c|<ε$.

Note: A norm ‖⋅‖ is said to be strictly monotone if
$$
||(x_{1}, y_{1})|| < ||(x_{2}, y_{2})|| $$ whenever $0 ≤ x_{1} ≤ x_{2}$,  $0 ≤ y_{1} < y_{2}$

or $0 ≤ x_{1} < x_{2}, 0 ≤ y_{1} ≤ y_{2}.$

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I have just edited the question. Sorry if it was not clear. I have proved the statement given an (a,b) (given an epsilon I found a delta that depends of (a,b)). I wanted to use the compactness of the ball but I didn't get anything.